# Why aren't these MongoDB document changes saved?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This code is intended to make changes in bulk to all the documents in a MongoDB collection. However there is no change at all to the documents in the collection after running this code. What is wrong with it?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    async = require('async'),
    Person = require('../../model/Person');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/people-questions');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

Person.find(function (err, people) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);

    //download bio info
    async.each(people, function(person, callback) {
        person.birthdateYear = '01';
        person.save();
        callback();
    });

    mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

I have verified that there are no changes made by leaving a mongo cli instance open in Terminal and running `db.people.find();` to see the field is not updated at all, and also queries such as `db.people.find({ "_id" : ObjectId("5379e6e21fe1e8e2fc364d17")});`, referencing specific IDs to verify that my Javascript code is indeed connected to the right database and is using the right collection (that ID came from a previous script using identical connection details to print out document IDs).

Also, I am using Mongoose. The Mongoose Schema was updated to include extra fields like birthdateYear after the original documents were created, but from the googling and Mongo Docs reading that I've done already it appears as though Schema changes shouldn't require any special work - you can set attributes against documents with the updated schema right away  (should be able to anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the updates are not persisted is that the connection to MongoDB is closed before the save() callbacks have a chance to complete. By ensuring all the save() callbacks complete before closing the connection, the data is saved.

Answer (score 0):

person.save is an async function
try something like

```
person.save (function(err){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    callback(); 
});
```

Comment: This did not solve the problem. Also the callback for save() is optional.